# differentiating between light sources in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, lighting

I am making a game with SpriteKit that involves a background, which is split into two layers. The bottom layer is something that visually, the player runs above, while the top layers is something the player runs below.

This effect has worked well, however as I am finishing up the game I am working with lighting. The player has a light around them, which I want to go under the top layer of the background, (ie: if they run under a bridge the light appears to go under the bridge as well). In addition, I also have ambient lights dotted around the map. With these lights I would like it if they lit up both the top and bottom layers of the background.

I am wondering how I use the lighting bitmask of the background and the category bitmask of the light to accomplish this. I have been messing around with it for a few hours now, and apple's documentation is unclear.

For reference, the two layers of the background are two separate SKSpriteNodes, one having a higher zposition than the other. If anyone knows how I can get the player light to only shine on the bottom layer, and have the ambient lights shine on both layers that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you completely lost with regard to how to use the botmasks or are you having some success but not getting the results you want? Are you familiar with the other SK bitmasks such as the collision and contactTest bitmasks?

Comment: After further investigation and many hours of tests, I have found that SpriteKit, has a built-in, hidden limit for the number of SKLightNodes in a given SKScene (9). Thank you for the help regardless!!